# jquery, не работает ожидание выполнения всех функций

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, почему у меня не работает ожидание выполнения всех функций в коде ниже? Вопреки ожиданиям, в консоли вначале появляется "Все выполнены", а затем по таймауту уже "Функция 1 2 3".

А хотелось бы, чтобы "Все выполнены" появлялись только после того, как все потроха функций отработают

Что я не так сделал?

```
let promises = [my(1), my(2), my(3)];                                

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() 
{
    console.log("Все выполнены")
});  

function my(b)
{                    
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        console.log("Функция " + b)
    }, 
    3000);
}
```

Comment: может быть потом что твоя функция должна возвращать promise или такой тип как $.Deferred()?

Comment: Ммм, покажи плиз на примере кода моего? Что где надо возвращать? А то так не пойму

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По **[документации](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)** надо в `when` передавать список либо `Deferred` либо `Promise` либо `Thenable`

Соответственно функция должна вернуть что-то из этого. Как пример:

```js
let promises = [my(1), my(2), my(3)];                                

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() 
{
    console.log("Все выполнены")
});  

function my(b) {                        
    let  d = $.Deferred();
    
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log("Функция " + b); 
        d.resolve(); 
    }, 3000);
    
    return d.promise();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```